# Grouping and counting how many instances of a specifc range there are / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project that functions as a parking system. I have a SQL table that has entries for both the datetime in which a car has parked and an entry for when it leaves, e.g.

```
LicencePlate: aa123aa, 
entry: 9/1/2022 2:32:10 PM 
departure 9/2/2022 2:32:24 PM 
SerialCode 489602
```

What I'm trying to do now is create a report that shows how many cars have parked for specific hours in specific days (i.e how many cars have parked for an hour today). I know this can be done by grouping the entries with Linq Group by in C# but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to go around doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from t in(from s in db.TableName.Where(x => x.departure != null)
                         select new {Transdate = s.StartTime, JobTime = Convert.ToInt16((s.departure - s.entry).Value.TotalHours)}).ToList()
                         group t by new { t.Transdate, t.JobTime } into grp
                         select new
                         {  grp.Key.Transdate,
                             grp.Key.JobTime,
                             Quantity = grp.Count()
                         }).ToList();
```